# A name fit for rappers

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, history

> My name is fit for rappers, though my title is a count;
>   The time I spent at sea no man of my day could surmount.
>   An empire's expansion was in large part my account;
>   The spice trade bought in riches in extremely large amounts.
>
> My journeys brought me gold and international acclaim;
>   Around the cape and all the way back was my route to fame.
>   I am not a Basque man, nor a player of a game,
>   Though you might believe so on the basis of my name.

Who am I?

Comment: Is the answer rot13(znepb cbyb )?

Comment: @R.D why not write an answer and explain how it fits the clues?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how it would fit the name of a rapper tho XD

Comment: @R.D if you think you have an answer, you should post it as such. however, the bit with the cape probably won't fit so well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> [Vasco da Gama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasco_da_Gama)?

My name is fit for rappers, though my title is a count;

> Maybe a play on "the gamer" -> "da gama"? (According to wikipedia, he was the 1st Count of Vidigueira)

The time I spent at sea no man of my day could surmount.
An empire's expansion was in large part my account;
The spice trade bought in riches in extremely large amounts.

My journeys brought me gold and international acclaim;
Around the cape and all the way back was my route to fame.

> All the five lines above point to his establishing the [sea route to India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Route), going around Africa, whose southernmost point is the Cape of Good Hope.

I am not a Basque man, nor a player of a game,
Though you might believe so on the basis of my name.

> He was Portuguese, and his name kind of sounds like "gamer".

Comment: I switched the names up! XD. This is why I don't like to answer history related questions XD

Comment: @R.D in fairness, your answer fits quite a few of the clues as well!

Comment: But it wasn't the right one, was it ?

Comment: @R.D yeah, that guy was more about the land route.